# Felgo live custom module not installed error

Tags: c++, qml, felgo

I have an app based on Felgo.

I added an implementation of some object via C++. It works ok than using Desktop client in Felgo Server, but when i try to use Felgo Live or connect Mobile device, i have an error:
**module "com.company.name" is not installed**.(As if i added it in **main.cpp** like **qmlRegisterType**)

I have followed the instructions to use C++ QML custom objects, but it does not work.

Am i doing something wrong or can i use this feature?

Answer (score 1):

You need to build your own app with Live Client enabled for your custom code to work, see https://felgo.com/doc/qml-hot-reload-felgo-live/#c-native-code-build-your-own-live-clients-with-the-felgo-live-module

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not a case of wrong setup of Felgo live client.
It is problem of missing path to custom module in Qml_IMPORT_PATH.